# How can i check there are no nulls in a list?

Tags: c#

I have a list , how can i check that for nulls ?

so i have a list clientIds

I do the following

```
var listA = (clientIds== null || !clientIds.Any(t => t.User.Email == userBody.Email))
```

but i want to check first that t.User is not null. User is an object in clientids

how can i do this ?

Comment: `var listA =(clientIds== null || !clientIds.Any(t => t.User != null && t.User.Email == userBody.Email))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the error that occurs when t.User is null in your C# code, you can modify the condition to include a null check before accessing the Email property. Here's an updated version of your code:

```cs
var listA = (clientIds == null || !clientIds.Any(t => t.User != null && t.User.Email == userBody.Email));
```

In the modified code, t.User != null is added as an additional check before accessing the Email property. This ensures that if t.User is null, the condition will evaluate to false and prevent the null reference error.

You can also use the null condition operator (`?.`) to conditionally access the Email property only if t.User is not null. If t.User is null, the entire expression t.User?.Email will evaluate to null, which will then be compared with userBody.Email.

```cs
var listA = clientIds == null || !clientIds.Any(t => t.User?.Email == userBody.Email);
```